# pass an attr to all good responses in sails js

Tags: javascript, sails.js, token, jwt, passport.js

I'm currently working on a angular + sails project. I'm using json web tokens for auth. It works fine but I wanna set a new token for every validated request that my angular app does.

This is my auth policy

```
passport.authenticate('jwt', function (error, user, info) {
     if (error) return res.serverError(error);
     if (!user) 
     return res.send({
       message: info.message,
       code: info.code,
       tokenError: info.name
     });
     // The token is ok past this line
     // I check the user again
     User.findOne({ email: user.email }, function (err, thisUser) {
       if (err) { return res.send(err); }
       if (!thisUser) {
         // send a bad response
       }
       req.user = user;
       // This is the new token that I wanna send to the frontend
       var newToken = AuthService.createToken(thisUser);
       next();
       });
})(req, res);
```

With this policy I can create the new token, but then I would need a way to include this token in every response, this Is the point where I'm stuck.
I gues I could do it manually in every controller action, but this is want I want to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to standardize your responses in Sails is to use the [custom responses](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/custom-responses) feature.  In short, instead of calling `res.send()` or `res.json()` in your controller actions, call `res.ok()` instead, and then customize the `api/responses/ok.js` file that is generated with every new Sails app.  This is the same response that Sails blueprints use as well!

In your case, you'd want to save the token onto the request object (e.g. `req.token`) in your policy code, then use that property in your logic inside of `ok.js`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best way for achieving this!